# Why is my Google App Engine site over quota?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm getting "Over Quota
This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later." on my GAE app.  It's not billing-enabled.  I ran a security scan against it today, which presumably triggered the over quota, but I can't explain why based on the information in the console.

Note that 1.59G has been used responding to 4578 requests.  That's an average of about 347k per request, but none of my responses should ever be that large.

[image: Console]

By filtering my logs I can see that there was no request today whose response size was greater than 25k.  So although the security scan generated a lot of small requests over its 14 minute run, it couldn't possibly account for 1.59G.  Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Note: mostly suppositions ...

The [Impact of Security Scanner on logs](https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/#impact_of_security_scanner_on_logs) section mentions:

> Some traces of the scan will appear in your log files. For instance,
>   the security scanner generates requests for unlikely strings such as
>   "~sfi9876" and "/sfi9876" in order to examine your application's error
>   pages; these intentionally invalid page requests will show up in your
>   logs.

My interpretation is that some of the scan requests will **not** appear in the app's logs.

I *guess* it's not impossible for some of the scanner's requests to similarly not be counted in the app's request stats, which *might* explain the suspicious computation results you reported. I don't see any mention of this in the docs to validate or invalidate this theory. However...

In the [Pricing, costs, and traffic](https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/#pricing_costs_and_traffic) section I see:

> Currently, a large scan stops after 100,000 test requests, not
>   including requests related to site crawling. (Site crawling requests
>   are not capped.)

A couple of other quotes from [Google Cloud Security Scanner](https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/) doc:

> The Google Cloud Security Scanner identifies security vulnerabilities
>   in your Google App Engine web applications. It crawls your
>   application, following all links within the scope of your starting
>   URLs, and attempts to exercise as many user inputs and event handlers
>   as possible.

---

> Because the scanner populates fields, pushes buttons, clicks links,
>   and so on, it should be used with caution. The scanner could
>   potentially activate features that change the state of your data or
>   system, with undesirable results. For example:
>
> - In a blog application that allows public comments, the scanner may    post test strings as comments on all your blog articles.
> - In an email sign-up page, the scanner may generate large numbers of    test emails.

These quotes suggest that, depending on your app's structure and functionality, the number of requests can be fairly high. Your app would need to be **really** basic for the quoted kinds of activities to be achieved in 4578 requests - *kinda* supporting the above theory that some scanner requests might not be counted in the app's stats.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. The docs imply but do not explicitly state that the test is done entirely via HTTP requests. Also, the scan report listed all the URLs tested, and they are all accessible from the root. If it had looked at my app.yaml, for example, it would have found others, so I don't think it has any privilege an attacker wouldn't have.

So I think it's behaving like an external attacker, i.e. everything should be explainable by the request logs if that's true.

At least I have conformation that the numbers don't add up. :-)